# How to include "Plan information" when creating ARM VM from a captured image using Powershell?

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I have a ARM VM created from a Marketplace: bitnami LAMP (Ubuntu)
I've successfully captured an image. During the capture I've saved the json template.

Using a template based on that I can successfully create new VMs via the portal's Template Deployment facility interactively. (so the captured image is OK). Please note: That json template **do include** plan information, see below

However my original goal is to create new ARM VMs based on the captured image **using Powershell**

All seems to work however in the last command New-AzureRmVM returns and error stating:

> Creating a virtual machine from Marketplace image requires Plan
>   information in the request.

*Obviously this information is missing, but I can not find out how to add it.*

**Here is what I've tried:**

- I've examined the $vm variable (what is the parameter of the New-AzureRmVM command) and its Plan property is empty. (as expected)
- I've searched for appropiate Add-AzureRmVm... commands with no success
- I've tried to set manually the Plan property and its subproperties in ***all caseing*** combinations: all thows error. (like $vm.Plan.Publisher="bitnami")

Actually the original capture's json template contains that Plan intomation:

```
  },
  "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "plan": {
    "name": "5-6",
    "publisher": "bitnami",
    "product": "lampstack"
  }
```

Again, the captured image (the .vhd) what this script tries to use is confirmed OK, because with the very same captured image I can create new ARM VMs via the portal's Template Deployment facility.

---

I think the source is not too important this case (there are no error in it, just missing things, but that missing thing is clearly stated in the question) 
but I attach the source anyway... **Optional reading**.

```
# Existing resource parameters
$subscriptionName =  'Visual Studio Premium with MSDN'
$rgName = "rg-wp"
$location = "westeurope"
$stName = 'mystorage' 
$sourceImageUri = 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/system/Microsoft.Compute/Images/vhds/template-osDisk.be7b0cf4-a28b-47f9-89c7-43887f1570ab.vhd' 

# Creation settings:
$vmSize = 'Standard_DS2'
$vmSuffix = 'wp-11'

#Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName

# Get the storage account
#$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | ? StorageAccountName -EQ $stName
$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -AccountName $stName -ResourceGroupName $rgName 

# Enable verbose output and stop on error
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
#$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$adminUsername = 'myusername'
$adminPassword = 'mypassword'

$vmName = '{0}-vm' -f $vmSuffix
$nicName = '{0}-nic' -f $vmSuffix
$ipName = '{0}-pip' -f $vmSuffix
$domName = '{0}-mzpx' -f $vmSuffix
$vnetName = '{0}-vn' -f $vmSuffix
$nsgName= '{0}-nsg' -f $vmSuffix


# Networking:
Write-Verbose 'Creating Virtual Network'  
$vnetDef = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -Name $vnetName -AddressPrefix '10.0.0.0/16'
Write-Verbose 'Adding subnet to Virtual Network'  
$vnet = $vnetDef | Add-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name 'Subnet-1' -AddressPrefix '10.0.0.0/24' | Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork

Write-Verbose 'Creating Public IP'  
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -Name $ipName -DomainNameLabel $domName -AllocationMethod Dynamic
Write-Verbose 'Creating NIC'  
$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsgName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location
Write-Verbose 'Network Security Group'  
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -Name $nicName -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

# Configuring VM
Write-Verbose 'Creating VM Config'  
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize 

# Specify local administrator account, and then add the NIC
$cred = New-Object PSCredential $adminUsername, ($adminPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) # you could use Get-Credential instead to get prompted
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Linux -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred 
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id

# Specify the OS disk
$diskName = '{0}-osdisk' -f $vmSuffix
$osDiskUri = '{0}vhds/{1}{2}.vhd' -f $storageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString(), $vmName.ToLower(), $diskName
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $diskName -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage -SourceImageUri $sourceImageUri -Linux

Write-Verbose 'Creating VM...'  

$result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of five days ago, and Azure Powershell version 1.2.2 they added a new cmdlet to the AzureRM.Compute - `Set-AzureRmVMPlan`

This let's you configure the plan parameter like this -

```
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -vmName $vmName -vmSize $vmSize

Set-AzureRmVMPlan -VM $vm -Publisher bitnami -Product lampstack -Name "5-6"
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $vhdName -VhdUri $vhdUri -Linux -CreateOption attach -Verbose
```

Comment: Michael, many thanks, trying... I am lucky that not a week ago started this project... :-) .(Sorry for the off topic question but what is the recommended way to update the Azure related PowerShell modules?)

Comment: @g.pickardou I'm vaguely aware that there is a Powershell cmd that does that - but I can never quite remember it - so I just downloaded the msi and ran it.

Comment: It works, confirmed. Now the script creates and starts a new VM clone, which is _usable_

Answer (score 2):

The following command in azure cli provides the information.
Example run below.

`azure vm image show --location westus --publisher paloaltonetworks --offer vmseries1 --sku bundle1 --version 7\.1\.1 --json`

```
[
  {
    "id": "/Subscriptions/subscription-id/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/westus/Publishers/paloaltonetworks/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/vmseries1/Skus/bundle1/Versions/7.1.1",
    "name": "7.1.1",
    "location": "westus",
    "plan": {
      "publisher": "paloaltonetworks",
      "name": "bundle1",
      "product": "vmseries1"
    },
    "osDiskImage": {
      "operatingSystem": "Linux"
    },
    "dataDiskImages": []
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that ends up here like I did, if you don't know the publisher or anything.

Save variables for new vm name $VM_NAME, resource group $RESOURCE_GROUP, and location $REGION, then run the following commands and create associated variables:

```
VM_NAME=<new-vm-name>
RESOURCE_GROUP=<my-resource-group>
REGION=<my-disks-location>
```

Get $PLAN_NAME, $PLAN_PRODUCT, $PLAN_PUBLISHER
**this command can take forever. you can shorten the wait if you can provide '--publisher', '--offer' or '--sku'.*

```
az vm image list --location $REGION --all -o table | grep <any-keyword>

PLAN_NAME=<output-from-command-above>
PLAN_PRODUCT=<output-from-command-above>
PLAN_PUBLISHER=<output-from-command-above>
```

Get available disks and save to variables $OS_DISK and $OS_TYPE

```
az disk list -o table

OS_DISK=<output-from-command-above>
OS_TYPE=<output-from-command-above>
```

Get list of nics (if available) and save to variables $NIC

```
az network nic list -o table

NIC=<output-from-command-above>
```

Get available vm sizes and save to variables $VM_SIZE

```
az vm list-sizes -l $REGION -o table

VM_SIZE=<output-from-command-above>
```

Once all the variables are set you can run this command to recreate the machine:

```
az vm create \
  --name $VM_NAME \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --attach-os-disk $OS_DISK \
  --os-type $OS_TYPE \
  --location $REGION \
  --size $VM_SIZE \
  --plan-name $PLAN_NAME \
  --plan-product $PLAN_PRODUCT \
  --plan-publisher $PLAN_PUBLISHER \
  --nics $NIC
```

Answer (score 0):

set-azurermvmplan command fixed the error. We should get all the parameters from automation script section of portal.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "edit"/update the VM and add the Plan to it easily, but are recieving the error:

> Azure Error: CannotSetPlanOnUpdate
>
> Message: This resource was created without a plan. A new plan cannot be associated with an update.

You can retrive a PowerShell object with the VM configuration with:

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "<Res-Grp>" -Name "<VM-Name>"
```

then do the edit as suggested by michael-b

```
Set-AzureRmVMPlan -VM $vm -Publisher bitnami -Product lampstack -Name "5-6"
```

Then delete the VM via the Portal (do not close the Powershell Window!)
Then do a redeploy with:

```
Update-AzureRmVM -VM $vm
```