# The term 'Set-AzureRmVMPlan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-marketplace, azure-vm-templates

I am trying to create a VM on Azure using powershell script in Azure Automation. This VM is to be created from marketplace. So I need to use cmdlet 'Set-AzureRmVMPlan' in my script.

> $vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $inVMName -VMSize $vmSize
>
> Set-AzureRmVMPlan -VM $vm -Publisher "kali-linux" -Product
>   "kali-linux" -Name "kali"

This script works fine when I run it from Powershell ISE however when I put this command in Azure Automation Runbook then Azure doesn't recognize this command. I get below error,

> Set-AzureRmVMPlan : The term 'Set-AzureRmVMPlan' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>
> operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try
>
> again.
>
> At restore-vhd-backups:8 char:8
>
> - - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureRmVMPlan:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

So I further investigate and found that this command is not available in cmdlet list at page "Edit PowerShell Runbook" (see below image)
[image: CMDLET List in Azure Portal Automation Runbook Edit]
[image: CMDLET in Powershell ISE]

I also got to know that this cmdlet was added in Azure Powershell last year from below link

[How to include "Plan information" when creating ARM VM from a captured image using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871496/how-to-include-plan-information-when-creating-arm-vm-from-a-captured-image-usi)

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is happening here, Azure Automation uses the old version of the Module, you have to go to Azure Automation Blade > Assets > Modules > Browse Gallery and reimport AzureRM.Profile and AzureRM.Compute.

[image: reference image]
[image: reference image]

Comment: thanks @4c74356b41, it worked. I didn't observe this before.