# Azure: Creating VM from existing VHD gives VMMarketplaceInvalidInput

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I had to delete a VM but kept the VHD and want to recreate the VM with this one since there is necessary data on it. What I did in the web interface:

- Made sure the vhd is unattached
- clicked in the vhd status page "create new virtual machine"
- choose a size and left the rest as it was
- created the vm

Now it says:

> Error at provision. Creating a virtual machine from Marketplace image
>   requires Plan information in the request. VM:
>   '/subscriptions/a566b4bb-3fe4-4e2b-88ec-bb627e8c2d89/resourceGroups/dev-ext-west-host-/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/'..
>   VMMarketplaceInvalidInput

I really need to get the vm running again with this vhd, any ideas on this one?

EDIT:
I did follow these steps for creating it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized-portal#create-a-vm-from-a-disk

Answer (score 2):

Following your steps, I can create a new VM from unattached DISK using the Azure portal without any error. You can check [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized-portal#create-a-vm-from-a-disk) on your side and try it again.

It looks like you require Plan information in the request for some specific images. The [Set-AzureRmVMPlan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmplan?view=azurermps-6.13.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-6.6.0) cmdlet sets the Azure Marketplace plan information for a virtual machine.

There is a [SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871496/how-to-include-plan-information-when-creating-arm-vm-from-a-captured-image-usi)

```
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -vmName $vmName -vmSize $vmSize

Set-AzureRmVMPlan -VM $vm -Publisher bitnami -Product lampstack -Name "5-6"
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $vhdName -VhdUri $vhdUri -Linux -CreateOption attach -Verbose
```

Comment: Thank you, I did follow these steps. For the rest, I will check it and come back

Comment: What I didn't mention, I try to achieve this in the web interface. But maybe I should try it with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

As @nancy-xiong stated you need to add a plan during the recreation of the VM.

You will have to remember what image the VM was created from.  The problem is that image/plan might no longer be available and the Plan must match for recreation.

Hope this helps.