# Capturing 'Specialized' image of Virtual machine created on Azure Resource Management Portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

How can we capture a specialized image of a virtual machine (windows or linux) that is created on Azure Resource Manager. Actually there is a tool (https://resources.azure.com/) but it creates a 'generalized' image. 
Please guide

Comment: This is a duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841458/

Comment: okay, you mean the attached disk of resource manager based (customized) VM actually is its specialized image?? if it is so, then how can we get the customizations in vms created from that vhd?

Comment: If you start with a blank Ubuntu build, and copy that disk it will be a blank Ubuntu build, if you install NGINX and then take a copy you will have a blank Ubuntu build with NGINX installed. So install, configure whatever you need and then copy it out and you'll have a specialised image that you can deploy as much as you need

Comment: ok, great..  instead of copying, can't we use the url (in deployment template file)where the vhd already exists that is something like https://<storageacountname>.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/vhdname.vhd?

Comment: If you detach the original image from the VM, you should be able to use the `-fromimage` option which will use that as a base image to create a new disk from

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is impossible.. You have to make a generalized copy of your disk so you can be able to deploy it on a new VM using Resource Manager Model.. If you're on the Classic Model, you can simply Capture an Image of your VM and deploy as much as you want VMs out of it.

Answer (score 0):

On ARM mode, for Specialized image, you could copy your VHD to another storage account. The copied VHD is a Specialized image. You could use the VHD to recreate a new VM which has your data. You had better copy the VHD when the VM is stopped. More information please refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-vhd-copy)